# Issue with uppercase author names in the references (abntex2)

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, abnt

I'm using abntex2 package and I've got an issue with citations in which the author has a composed name.
The .bib file entry is like this:

```
@incollection{BarbosaFilho2016,
address = {Rio de Janeiro},
author = {{Barbosa Filho}, Fernando de Holanda and Turra, Cássio M. and 
Wajnman, Simone and Guimarães, Raquel},
booktitle = {BONELLI, R. \& VELOSO, F. (Org.) A crise de crescimento do 
Brasil.},
pages = {87-109},
publisher = {Elsevier},
title = {Transição demográfica, oferta de trabalho e crescimento econômico 
no Brasil},
year = {2016}
}
```

When I use the command \citeonline, I have the following result (which is correct):

```
Barbosa Filho et al. (2016)
```

But in the references section in the end of the text I have:

```
Barbosa Filho, F. d. H. et al. Transição (...)
```

Why the name of the author is in lower case and not in the upper case like the others (they are single-named). How can I fix that? If I simply take out the brackets "{" in the bib file, it changes to "FILHO" instead of "BARBOSA FILHO", which is what I wanted.

Thank you in advance!

Wagner

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) According to [this](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87hufflen.pdf) you can write `de Holanda Barbosa, Filho, Fernando` instead to get the `Jr.` part correct and still allow BibTeX to make the name uppercase later. I haven't tested, though...

Comment: Hello @PhelypeOleinik, It worked this way! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great :) Do you want me to post an answer or can I close the question as "solved in the comments"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved in the comments.

Comment: Ok, you can close it as solved in comments! Thank you